# How to lock the portrait view even if screen rotate to landscape in ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am new to iOS development. I am working on app which have an pdf view in which we can edit and fill the form. My problem is when i rotate the device in landscape mode i need my pdf view to be in center of the screen it should not be stretch with the size of the screen size. i need to give fix size to my pdf view as in portrait and want blank space in remaining area of screen. How to do that please guide me. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: is your app fully portrait view ....?

Comment: no some view needs to open in portrait and some are in landscape

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what versions of iOS your app is targeted for and how your view is being presented (UINavigationController or not). Can you provide these details?

Comment: ya..by uinavigation controller

Answer (score 0):

Use this setting[image] . Uncheck landscape option in setting section.

Comment: by this setting its open portrait view only but want open landscape view but pdf in it is in portrait form...so give any suggestion...

Comment: I'm little confused!. I assume  webview is used to load PDF.  Constraints might help you